# iPad MPMoviePlayerController - Disable Fullscreen

Tags: ipad, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, fullscreen

Is there a way to disable the fullscreen button of the MPMoviePlayerController ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way. Hopefully with the next update.

Answer (score 11):

Just did it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(movieEventFullscreenHandler:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification 
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(movieEventFullscreenHandler:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification 
                                               object:nil];

    self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
}

- (void)movieEventFullscreenHandler:(NSNotification*)notification {
    [self.moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:NO];
    [self.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, I thought I could use this to trigger an alert to explain why fullscreen wasn't allowed in the current context and force it to stay in embedded mode. Unfortunately what actually happens is that you still get the transition to full screen and then it kicks back to being embedded which looks really horrid.

Comment: I just tried doing this, but unfortunately fullscreen ignores the MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded and uses FullScreen, which, when I toggle fullscreen then, it goes even larger :(

Answer (score 7):

Depending on your needs, you can also simply disable all user interactions on the player view.

```
player.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can set controlStyle to Fullscreen. these controls are somewhat different, but it doesn't feature a Fullscreen button!

```
[_moviePlayerController setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
```

Comment: Genius! This should definitely the best answer.

Answer (score 5):

You could hide the playback controls and add your own custom ones, this will prevent the default buttons being rendered at all

I.e with

```
[player setMovieControlMode:MPMovieControlModeNone];
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately none of above worked for me properly, so picking the above I implemented the following (and worked fine):

1. Hide the full screen button.

Add this code in the method where you initialise the movie player.

```
    ....

        //Because we have to wait until controllers are shown

        [self performSelector:@selector(hideFullscreenButton) withObject:self afterDelay:0.5];

    ...
```

Add  the methods:

```
    -(void) hideFullscreenButton{

        //Hide full screen mode button

        [self hideFullscreenSubview:movieClip.view.subviews];

    }



    -(void) hideFullscreenSubview:(NSArray*)arr{

        for(UIView *v in arr){

            if([v.subviews count]>0)

                [self hideFullscreenSubview:v.subviews];

            else

                NSLog(@"%@",v);

            if(v.frame.origin.x==975 ){

                v.hidden=TRUE;

            }

        }

    }
```

The problem relies that there is no tag to identify which view you have to hide. In my case I figure it out by the view coordinates.

2. Overwrite tap gestures for do not allowing fullscreen zoom.

```
 movieClip.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;    

    //Disable tap for not allowing that video control set on a full screen mode.
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(doSingleTap)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [movieClip.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];



    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(doDoubleTap)];
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [movieClip.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
    [singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];
```

And add the selector methods:

```
    -(void) doSingleTap{
        //DO NOTHING!!!
    }

    -(void) doDoubleTap{
        //DO NOTHING!!!
    }
```

Comment: The first solution worked perfect for me, thx! At the bottom the Swift version

Comment: it hides the scrubber not the full screen button

Answer (score 4):

There's a cheat:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *mpc = (...some instance...)
UIView *fsbutton = [[mpc view] viewWithTag:512];
[fsbutton setHidden:YES];
```

The main catch is, you have to do it in `viewDidAppear:` or similar, because the MoviePlayer view sets itself up somewhere inside `didMoveToWindow` or `didMoveToSuperview`, which happen after `viewWillAppear:`. So you get a brief flash of the fullscreen button. Other obvious catches include: brittle vs. Apple changing that 512 tag value (although it works in 3.2 - 4.2); and of course Apple would rather you not do this.

The endorsed solution is to set the control style to `MPMovieControlStyleNone` and roll your own transport controls, which is more work.

Comment: The other problem is that the pinch to zoom gesture which also brings the user into full screen circumvents this neat idea.

Comment: and try to remove gestures

Comment: Apple will likely reject your app if you try to modify the MPMovePlayerController beyond the public API.  Here is a quote from [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):    
"Consider a movie player view to be an opaque structure. You can add your own custom subviews to layer content on top of the movie but you **must never modify any of its existing subviews.**"

Answer (score 3):

in order to disable switch to full screen mode, either form button or pinch gesture, you can use this:

```
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
moviePlayer.view.userInteractionEnabled =NO;
```

Answer (score 2):

Wired does this. For the videos that start in fullscreen, they have the standard MPMoviePlayerController controls, but are missing the fullscreen buttons. And they're using the standard built-in ones, since they suddenly got an AirPlay button with 4.2.

Answer (score 2):

Fullscreen button along with pause button can be removed.

```
[self.videoPlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple block to remove pinch zoom here

Hope it help

it work with me on iOS6

```
 for (UIView *view in  moviePlayer.view.subviews) {

    for(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinch in view.gestureRecognizers){
    if([pinch isKindOfClass:[UIPinchGestureRecognizer class]])
        [view removeGestureRecognizer:pinch];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked on iOS 7, iPhone 5s.

```
Add Notification:

MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification : @"moviePlayFullscreenNote:"

- (void)moviePlayFullscreenNote:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    if (notification.object == self.videoPlayer)
    {
        [self.videoPlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
        self.videoPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
    }
}
```

Notice that I only listen for "DID" and not the "WILL" notification as well as running it animated. I think this works as it gives the system time to react.  When I used the "WILL" and "DID" as noted in answers above it led to a black screen with no controls. There is a slight glitch that is visible when the transition occurs, but I need the play/scrub buttons from embedded.

Answer (score 1):

If the **only** thing you want to do is disable pinch to go full screen (i.e. keep interaction enabled and whatever control style you want), you can use this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    NSSet *set = [event allTouches];
    NSArray *arr = [set allObjects];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.count; i++) {
        UITouch *touch = (UITouch *) [arr objectAtIndex:i];

        NSArray *recognisers = touch.gestureRecognizers;
        for (UIGestureRecognizer *recogniser in recognisers) {
            if (recogniser.enabled && [recogniser isMemberOfClass:[UIPinchGestureRecognizer class]]) {
                recogniser.enabled = NO;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the Swift version of the first solution of Javier Calatrava Llavería:

```
func hideFullScreenButton() {
    self.hideFullScreenSubview((self.moviePlayerController?.view.subviews)!)
}

func hideFullScreenSubview(subviews: [UIView]) {
    for view: UIView in subviews {
        if view.subviews.count > 0 {
            self.hideFullScreenSubview(view.subviews)
        }
        if view.frame.origin.x == 631 {
            view.hidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

And when the user taps on Play:

```
self.performSelector(#selector(VideoViewController.hideFullScreenButton), withObject: self, afterDelay: 0.5)
```

(VideoViewController is the view controller in which I have the MPMoviePlayerController)

Answer (score 0):

I know, it's a little outdated, but anyway. I did some research in that direction, and looks like a found an answer. I do not know, why it's working, but it is.

```
-(void) playMovieAtURL: (NSURL*) theURL {

    MPMoviePlayerController* theMovie =
    [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: theURL];
    //That line is for ARC. Without it, it may not work.
    self.moviePlayer = theMovie;
    theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    theMovie.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
    theMovie.repeatMode  = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
    //Here you'd better use your custom ViewController subclass, if you want autorotating and all that stuff.
    UIViewController * vc = [UIViewController new];
    [vc.view addSubview:theMovie.view];
    theMovie.fullscreen  = YES;
    theMovie.view.frame = vc.view.bounds;
    vc.view = theMovie.view;
    [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
    theMovie.fullscreen  = YES;

    [theMovie prepareToPlay];
    [theMovie play];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
}
```

// When the movie is done, release the controller.

```
-(void) myMovieFinishedCallback: (NSNotification*) aNotification
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    MPMoviePlayerController* theMovie = [aNotification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 removeObserver: self
 name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
 object: theMovie];
    [self.moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
    self.moviePlayer = nil;
    // Release the movie instance created in playMovieAtURL:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a `UIView` or `UIButton` with transparent background on top of the view that shows the video, so that the user won't be able to tap on the view that contains the video.