# MPMoviePlayerController controls - remove fullscreen and aspect buttons?

Tags: iphone, ipad, video, controls

The documentation shows 3 control styles:

```
MPMovieControlStyleNone,
MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded,
MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen,
MPMovieControlStyleDefault = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen
```

I want the controls to mimic the kind found in Apple's "Videos" app, which do not have a fullscreen button or an aspect ratio button. None of the above do this. How do we achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Just looked for a similar solution (following up on a client request saying: "I want the same behavior than in Apple's app Videos").
Result of my research:  It is not possible.

In fullscreen mode, you either:

- **show no control** (and the user can't control the playing of the video)
- **show the controls when starting to play the video** (and they automatically disappear after 5 seconds).

Apple has likely used a private API for this.

Answer (score 0):

By iterating all MPMoviePlayerController subviews, then hide the full screen button [stackoverflow.com/a/27482687/928599](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27482687/928599)

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can hide the full screen button. Use MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen with MPMovieScalingModeFill property. My example code is as under:

```
mpplayerObject.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
[mpplayerObject setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeFill];
```