# MPMoviePlayerController adding UIButton to view that fades with controls

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to add a UIButton to the view of a *MPMoviePlayerController* along with the standard controls.  The button appears over the video and works as expected receiving touch events, but I would like to have it fade in and out with the standard controls in response to user touches.

I know I could accomplish this by rolling my own custom player controls, but it seems silly since I am just trying to add one button.

***EDIT***

If you recursively traverse the view hierarchy of the *MPMoviePlayerController*'s view eventually you will come to a view class called *MPInlineVideoOverlay*.  You can add any additional controls easily to this view to achieve the auto fade in/out behavior.

There are a few gotchas though, it can sometimes take awhile (up to a second in my experience) after you have created the *MPMoviePlayerController* and added it to a view before it has initialized fully and created it's *MPInlineVideoOverlay* layer.  Because of this I had to create an instance variable called *controlView* in the code below because sometimes it doesn't exist when this code runs.  This is why I have the last bit of code where the function calls itself again in 0.1 seconds if it isn't found.  I couldn't notice any delay in the button appearing on my interface despite this delay.

```
-(void)setupAdditionalControls {
    //Call after you have initialized your MPMoviePlayerController (probably viewDidLoad)
    controlView = nil;
    [self recursiveViewTraversal:movie.view counter:0];

    //check to see if we found it, if we didn't we need to do it again in 0.1 seconds
    if(controlView) {
            UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [controlView addSubview:backButton];
    } else {
            [self performSelector:@selector(setupAdditionalControls) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    }
}


-(void)recursiveViewTraversal:(UIView*)view counter:(int)counter {
    NSLog(@"Depth %d - %@", counter, view); //For debug
    if([view isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"MPInlineVideoOverlay")]) {
            //Add any additional controls you want to have fade with the standard controls here
            controlView = view;
    } else {
            for(UIView *child in [view subviews]) {
                    [self recursiveViewTraversal:child counter:counter+1];
            }
    }
}
```

It isn't the best solution, but I am posting it in case someone else is trying to do the same thing.  If Apple was to change the view structure or class names internal to the control overlay it would break.  I am also assuming you aren't playing the video full screen (although you can play it fullscreen with embeded controls).  I also had to disable the fullscreen button using the technique described here because the *MPInlineVideoOverlay* view gets removed and released when it is pressed: [iPad MPMoviePlayerController - Disable Fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650350/ipad-mpmovieplayercontroller-disable-fullscreen/5035449#5035449)

Calling *setupAdditionalControls* when you receive the fullscreen notifications described above will re-add your additional controls to the UI.

Would love a more elegant solution if anyone can suggest something other than this hackery I have come up with.

Comment: For iPhone 5, instead of find for a 'MPInlineVideoOverlay' class try to find 'MPFullScreenTransportControls' class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution to the same problem was:

- Add the button as a child of the *MPMoviePlayerController*'s view;
- fade the button in and out using animation of its `alpha` property, with the proper durations;
- handle the player controller's `touchesBegan`, and use that to toggle the button's visibility (using its alpha);
- use a timer to determine when to hide the button again.

By trial-and-error, I determined that the durations that matched the (current) iOS ones are:

- fade in: 0.1s
- fade out: 0.2s
- duration on screen: 5.0s (extend that each time the view is touched)

Of course this is still fragile; if the built-in delays change, mine will look wrong, but the code will still run.

Comment: Thanks, this should work, I think Apple changing fade durations would be far less likely than changing the view structure. Will go with this.

Comment: can you give some example how do you handle the touchedBegan? the player is not a UIVIew so it is not possible to subclass it. Also how do you replace the button when the orientation changes?

Comment: @JoãoNunes use an `MPMoviePlayerViewController` instead and subclass it and use it's `moviePlayer` property to play the movie. As for the orientation changes, you have to re-calculate the `CGRect` for the button

Comment: For iOS 7 the pertinent class name has changed to `MPVideoPlaybackOverlayView` and the property to observe is `hidden`, since `alpha` no longer changes.