# How can I add a KVO to a MPMoviePlayerController such that I can detect when controls are visible

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to be able to make my custom controls appear and disappear with the standard control for a `MPMoviePlayerController`.  What is the best approach?

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: Do you have custom controls that you want to use instead of the standard ones?

Comment: No, I would like to use my custom controls in addition to the MPMoviePlayer standard controls if possible.  I have them appearing but have nothing setup on how to make them appear and disappear with the standard controls.  I think it has something to do with the MPInlineVideoOverlay view but can't quite figure out the mechanics of how to do what I want do do.

Answer (score 4):

I believe I found the solution.  If anyone else needs this functionality, here is how I got it to work:

I used the code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113735/mpmovieplayercontroller-adding-uibutton-to-view-that-fades-with-controls) to find the MPInlineVideoOverlay subview in the MPMoviePlayer view array.  Then I modified it as follows:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath 
                          ofObject:(id)object 
                            change:(NSDictionary *)change 
                           context:(void *)context {
```

float newValue = 0;
    if([change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] != [NSNull null]) 
    {
        newValue = [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] floatValue];
    }
    NSLog(@"player controls are visible: %@", newValue ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    self.controlsView.alpha = newValue;
}

-(void)recursiveViewTraversal:(UIView*)view counter:(int)counter {
    NSLog(@"Depth %d - %@", counter, view); //For debug
    if([view isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"MPInlineVideoOverlay")]) {
        //Add any additional controls you want to have fade with the standard controls here
        mainControlsView = view;
    } else {
        for(UIView *child in [view subviews]) {
            [self recursiveViewTraversal:child counter:counter+1];
        }
    }
}

-(void)setupAdditionalControls {
    //Call after you have initialized your MPMoviePlayerController (probably viewDidLoad)
    mainControlsView = nil;
    [self recursiveViewTraversal:moviePlayer.view counter:0];

    //check to see if we found it, if we didn't we need to do it again in 0.1 seconds
    if(mainControlsView) {
        [mainControlsView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"alpha"      options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
    } else {
        [self performSelector:@selector(setupAdditionalControls) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    }
}`

Where mainControlsView is the standard Apple controls for MPMoviePlayer and self.controlsView is my view with my custom controls.  I Key Value Observe the alpha property on the standard controls view and change mine to match whenever it changes.

Rob

Comment: For iOS 7 the pertinent class name has changed to `MPVideoPlaybackOverlayView` and the property to observe is `hidden`, since `alpha` no longer changes.