# How to add a UIImageView over a MPMoviePlayerController | iOS | Objective C

Tags: ios, uiimageview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a controller where I displays a video using MPMoviePlayerController. And I need to put an image over the video.

I am trying with the following code, but it doesn't show up. What I am missing?

```
// method to play the video
- (void)playVideoInLoopMode:(BOOL)loop {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myvideo" ofType:@"m4v"]];

    MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    mp.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

    if (loop) {
        mp.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;        
    }

    mp.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
    self.player = mp;
    [self.view addSubview:self.player.view];

    [self.player prepareToPlay];

    [self.player play];
}

// method to add the image
- (void) addImageLayer {
    image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage"]];
    image.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:image];
}
```

First I am running the video with the method: [self playVideoInLoopMode:YES] and after 5 seconds I am trying to put the image layer with the method [self addImageLayer];

In my AppDelegate.h I have this code in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
 MyViewController *myVC = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];

    [self.window addSubview:myVC.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the image view to the mp.view and then u add the mp.view to the general view
for example if the image will be always the same u can add it in your starting code and delete the method to add the view...

```
// method to play the video
- (void)playVideoInLoopMode:(BOOL)loop 
{
   NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myvideo" ofType:@"m4v"]];

   MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
   mp.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

   if (loop) 
   {
       mp.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;        
   }

   mp.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
   self.player = mp;
   [self.view addSubview:self.player.view];
   image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"]];
   image.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
   [self.player addSubview:image];
   [self.player prepareToPlay];
   [self.player play];
}
```

Comment: It seems that I can "change" the player view before it starts but after the video start running I can't modify it. I've done as you said and I could add the image over the video player. But then I've tried to set image.hidden = YES before adding the view to player, and setting image.hidden = NO after the video was playing and the image doesn't show up :(

Comment: You might want to try hiding the view with the alpha property. I've been successfully doing that for a long time. See [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113735/mpmovieplayercontroller-adding-uibutton-to-view-that-fades-with-controls)

Comment: and I suggest you to use MPMoviePlayerViewController in place of MPMoviePlayerController...

Comment: I've solved as MartinKenny said using the alpha property. Calleth I had to use MPMoviePlayerController because I needed to be able to not show the player controllers.

Comment: You can do the same with the new one just go to the MPMoviePlayerController by movieplayerviewcontroller.moviePlayer cause if in your player you make a gesture separating two fingers it will enter on full screen mode and without controls u could not return ;)