# Remove/hide Full screen button from MPMoviePlayerController Standard Controls

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to **remove/hide** the full screen button from `MPMoviePlayerController` standard controls as full screen mode is creating lot of problems and also not a requirement of my app.I just want the `play`,`stop`,`forward`,`reverse` `controls`. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 17):

There's no standard way to do this. Here are your options.

You could set the `MPMoviePlayerController's` controlStyle to None and create your own custom controls. Cons: this is a lot of work.

You could use the `NSNotificationCenter` to intercept the `MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification` and immediately set fullScreen mode to NO. Cons: based on the iOS version of the user, this may cause a flicker or some glitchy effect.

You could go through the `MPMoviePlayerController` view's subviews until you get to a `MPInlineTransportControls` view which contains the controls, the `slider` and the `play/pause button` and the full screen button which are all of class `MPTransportButton`. Find that one and you can hide it or remove it from its superview. Cons: as of right now this passes app store reviews and works perfectly on all currently supported `iOS` versions. But this could change at any time. If Apple decides to redo their default video player you may end up with non working code.

Comment: in iOS 6 can't find MPInlineTransportControls view.

Comment: This answer was very helpful, if you're using the `NSNotificationCenter` method it's a bit wrong.  You should listen for  `MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification` and not `MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification`.  If you listen for `Will` instead of `Did` you will set the `fullscreen` property to `NO` before it's set to `YES` and the method will not work.  I also found a bug where the video disappears but continues to play after you call `setFullScreen:NO`.  To prevent this, I called `[video pause];` and then `[video play]` after my `setFullScreen` method.

Comment: By iterating all MPMoviePlayerController subviews http://stackoverflow.com/a/27482687/928599