# Hide/Disable Fullscreen button in MPMoviePlayer

Tags: ios, overlay, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have tried many solutions posted on SO but none of them worked for me.
I am using XCDYoutubeplayer to display a video in my app and I want to hide the Full screen button or disable done button from the control. I am running app on iOS 8.x and 9.x. Does someone knows any solution or only creating custom overlay controls is the solution ? I need only Play/Pause and scrubber to display to the user. I want to hide this button shown in screenshot

[image]

Comment: see this once bro , it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786652/removing-deactivating-fullscreen-button-on-movieplayercontrol

Comment: already tried all the solution on stack-overflow none of them is working