# Disable "exit fullscreen button" in MPMoviePlayer

Tags: ios, xamarin

I want to disable the button which exits the full screen mode in **MPMoviePlayer**.
To clarify which button see below screenshot!

[image]

I also want to exit when the done button is pushed so it is not possible to use the **MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification** as this is triggered for both buttons.

I am using xamarin and c# but any help in plain old objective-c is more than welcome too.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855906/remove-hide-full-screen-button-from-mpmovieplayercontroller-standard-controls

Comment: According to the link the only option is to create custom controls, I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Then it's not possible.