# How to disable FullScreen in MPMoviePlayerViewController in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am working with `MPMoviePlayerViewController`,

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *avPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
// [movieView prepareToPlay];

[avPlayer.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 100)];  // player's frame must match parent's
[avPlayer shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
[avPlayer shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
avPlayer.moviePlayer.scalingMode=MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
avPlayer.moviePlayer.useApplicationAudioSession=NO;
avPlayer.moviePlayer.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
//avPlayer.moviePlayer.repeatMode=MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
avPlayer.moviePlayer.scalingMode=MPMovieScalingModeFill;
[self.view addSubview: avPlayer.view];
```

This functionality working fine. But i need to disable fullscreen for `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. So, that i wrote

```
avPlayer.moviePlayer.fullscreen=NO;
```

But this is not working.

Will you please give me suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for disable full screen in `MPMoviePlayerViewController`.

```
moviePlayerController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
```

or check this for enter your view controller.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(Enter:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification 
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(Enter:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

i hope this code useful for you.

Comment: This will not properly function. Try this, use this code and then use a pinch gesture to scale up or down -> bam!

Answer (score -3):

Try this...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(movieEventFullscreenHandler:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification 
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(movieEventFullscreenHandler:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification 
                                               object:nil];

    self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
}

- (void)movieEventFullscreenHandler:(NSNotification*)notification {
    [self.moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:NO];
    [self.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];
}
```

**Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650350/ipad-mpmovieplayercontroller-disable-fullscreen)**